# Python, find if a range contains another smaller range from a list of ranges

Tags: python, range, subset

I am looking for a efficient and fast way to do the following in Python 3.x. I am open to using third party libraries such as Numpy as long as the performance is there.

I have a list of ranges containing hundreds of thousands of entries. They're not actually range()'s, but rather the boundary numbers, such as:

```
list_a = [(1, 100), (300, 550), (551, 1999)]
```

Then, I iterate over hundred of thousands of other ranges (boundary numbers). I want to find if they contain one of the existing ranges from above. For example:

```
(0, 600) contains list_a[0] and list_a[1]
(550, 2000) contains list_a[2]
(2000, 2200) does not contain an existing range
```

Right now, doing something similar to the following, which is way too slow for big amounts of data:

```
for start, end in get_next_range():
    for r in list_a:
        if r[0] >= start and r[1] <= end:
            # do something
        else:
            # do something else
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are they sorted?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad the first list can easily be sorted, not the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it following way using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
start = 0
finish = 600
lista = np.array([[1,100],[300,550],[551,1999]])
S = lista[:,0]>start
F = lista[:,1]<finish
contains = np.logical_and(S,F)
ind = list(np.flatnonzero(contains))
print(ind) #print [0, 1]
```

Explanation: firstly I made `lista` as `np.array`, then sliced it into two parts: one with lower bound (`[:,0]`) and second for upper bound (`[:,1]`) then used comparison operators, getting 1D `np.array`s of `bool`s. Using `np.logical_an`d I got single 1D `np.array` with `True`s for fullfiling condition and `False`s for rest. Finally I used `np.flatnonzero` to get indices of `True`s. This solution assumes that all data are in `(lowerboundary,upperboundary)` order. Please check if that solution is fast enough for your purpose.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tested on a small subset and this is going to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are sorted within, i.e. the range values are never (high, low),
this will compare **all** elements in a to **all** elements in b at the same time:

```
import numpy as np

list_a = [(1, 100), (300, 550), (551, 1999)]
list_b = [(0, 600), (550, 2000), (2000, 2200), (50, 70)]
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
comparison = np.logical_and(a[:, 1] >= b[:, 1, None], a[:, 0] <= b[:, 0, None])
idx_a, idx_b = idx = np.nonzero(comparison)
print(a[idx_a])
print(b[idx_b])

array([[   1,  100],
       [ 300,  550],
       [ 551, 1999]])

array([[   0,  600],
       [   0,  600],
       [ 550, 2000]])
```

This gives you the intervals in a that are contained in b. The indices are given in `idx_a` and `idx_b`.